eBPF function with void return type : verifier question
I ran a sample ebpf code with void  as return type and calling bpf_printk before returning. I was expecting this code to be rejected by the verifier. However, I was able to successfully load it into the kernel and it kind of damaged my networking subsystem as it was related to xdp  and had to restart my machine to get the networking working again.  Is this normal?
Kernel: Linux asus 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

int counter = 0;

SEC("xdp")
void error_packet_count(void *ctx) {
    bpf_printk("%d", counter);
    counter++;
    return;
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";


Since the question is vague "Is it normal?", following is just my opinion. Value returned by BPF function has nothing to do with kernel security, it cannot break the kernel. It's just undefined behavior of the probram which affects network functionality. The same "damage" may be done by returning XDP_DROP. There also must be fall-through case for invalid action values and packet must be dropped: https://prototype-kernel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/networking/XDP/implementation/xdp_actions.html.

TL;DR. It looks like the compiler is ignoring your void return value and adding an exit eBPF instruction regardless.

I've been able to reproduce this with the following program, here dumped by bpftool after being loaded in the kernel:
$ sudo bpftool prog dump xlated id 201
void error_packet_count(struct xdp_md * ctx):
; void error_packet_count(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
   0: (b7) r1 = 0
; ({ char _fmt[] = "Hello, World!\n"; bpf_trace_printk_(_fmt, sizeof(_fmt)); });
   1: (73) *(u8 *)(r10 -2) = r1
   2: (b7) r1 = 2593
   3: (6b) *(u16 *)(r10 -4) = r1
   4: (b7) r1 = 1684828783
   5: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -8) = r1
   6: (18) r1 = 0x57202c6f6c6c6548
   8: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r1
   9: (bf) r1 = r10
; 
  10: (07) r1 += -16
; ({ char _fmt[] = "Hello, World!\n"; bpf_trace_printk_(_fmt, sizeof(_fmt)); });
  11: (b7) r2 = 15
  12: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#-108752
; }
  13: (95) exit

We can see that, despite the C program having a void return value, the BPF program ends with an exit instruction. It looks like the compiler is automatically adding the exit instruction.

Interestingly, if you remove the call to bpf_trace_printk, it will then fail with:
0: (95) exit
R0 !read_ok

Here, the verifier complains that R0 is uninitialized. R0 contains the return code of your program and should therefore never be uninitialized at the end of your program.
Calling bpf_trace_printk avoids this verifier error because it will end up placing the return value of bpf_trace_printk in R0. Hence, whatever return value bpf_trace_printk is giving you will be your BPF program's return code.
